# Инициализация Gecko

Tags: c++

В документации сказано, что для выполнения начальной инициализации Gecko нужно вызвать:
nsresult NS_InitEmbedding(const char *aPath);
nsresult NS_TermEmbedding();
но поиск по всем .h файлам SDK ничего не дал. Как его иницилизировать тогда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти функции были удалены из SDK, используйте новые:

`XRE_InitEmbedding` (или `XRE_InitEmbedding2`)

`XRE_TermEmbedding`

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/build/nsXULAppAPI.h

Вот [пример инициализации](http://markmail.org/message/axz2uundt4qv73oh)

Comment: Безмерно благодарен) Всех благ Вам)

Comment: @ЛеонтийХачуев отметьте мой ответ решением (нажмите зеленую галочку слева)